# Making container size responsive

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles customizing my tabs because almost every change I make, causes everything to move everywhere. What I want is to make the full container and labels responsive to the screen size, so when the screen gets smaller, everything will get smaller as well, also the tab labels should center to the middle. I tried to give the positions `vw` positions instead of percentages but that did not work, the tabs and container still stay the same size when the screen gets smaller.

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 70vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 21px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_last {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 70vw;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 15vw;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tab_container {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would take a lot of them to make it the perfect size for every resolution but if there are no other options I will do it

Comment: Its hard to visualize the issue with the code you provided. The tab container is set to `70vw` and that seems to be working and resizing according to window dimensions. Could you post an example of what you mean by "everything moves everywhere"? Also, tab labels are already centered and middle aligned in reference to their individual tabs. Do you want the whole tab bar to center in the page?